# Signal child started with posix_spawn when parent exits

Tags: linux, process, signals, posix, glibc

Processes started via fork() can request to be signaled when their parent exits, using prctl(PR_SET_PDEATHSIG, SIGHUP).

How can I do the same when using posix_spawn to run a binary that I can't modify ?

EDIT: one workaround is to posix_spawn the same binary as the parent, and pass it the child binary and arguments into argv. And in main, call prctl and then call execv with the rest of the argv array.

Comment: What happens when you try the same way?

Comment: prctl(PR_SET_PDEATHSIG) is meant to be called in the child, and I can't control the child, it's a distro binary (I should have mentioned this).

Comment: Your suggestion of a "chained exec" binary, either a standalone utility or your own process image with different logic in `main` as you remark, is a great approach, since you want a Linux-specific process attribute set before a POSIX process creation call.  I suggest you post an answer to your own question.